# sstableloader returns `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Filter.db"`

Tags: cassandra

I've been using the Java API to create an SSTable by following the instructions on [this site](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated).

The program compiles and works fine; no errors.

However when I try to load the table using the following command `sstableloader -v -d 127.0.0.1 /path/to/sstable/keyspace/tablename` it returns an error. Here is the stack trace it outputs:

```
For input string: "Filter.db"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Filter.db"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:276)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:235)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Component.fromFilename(Component.java:120)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTable.tryComponentFromFilename(SSTable.java:160)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader$1.accept(SSTableLoader.java:84)
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:162)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:109)
```

---

**NOTES**

Tried to google it but there doesn't seem to be anything about this error.

The table that im loading into only has three columns: `( id uuid PRIMARY KEY, datablob text, tablename text )`.

I've also tried loading empty data and just auto generating a uuid to check that it's not the data I'm loading but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by upgrading Cassandra to the latest version; I was running the last 2.x release and now it's running the latest 3.0.7 version.